# Access control properties can set with True/False, but not with Boolean variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access database I have a global variable (`Global allowEditing as Boolean`) defined in a module (Main).  I set this variable, then I want to use it later at the form level to disable some buttons.  I'm having trouble with this.

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    ctl.Enabled = False            'Works for True or False            
    ctl.Enabled = allowEditing     'Throws error               
  Next
```

The error thrown is:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this
>   property or method.

Whats happening here and how can I use the boolean value?

Comment: What happens if the variable is defined locally or as `Public` rather than `Global`?

Comment: @creamyegg -Public throws same error.  And locally doesn't help me here, I want to run code once to set the value, then use in several forms.

Comment: Silly question, but what is the object type when it fails?  When I test similar code, a textbox works for both hard-coded and global values, but a label errors out with either.

Comment: what's the value of ctl.Enabled before it throws an error? what's the name of the control that fails?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables -No, this is the problem, you got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each control has a `ControlType` property.  You can take advantage of that property to disable only those you chose from among the controls which support the `Enabled` property.  This procedure will set the `Enabled` property for check boxes, combos, list boxes, and text boxes.

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    With ctl
        Select Case .ControlType
        Case acCheckBox, acComboBox, acListBox, acTextBox
            .Enabled = allowEditing
        Case Else
            ' pass
        End Select
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Error 438 is issued when you try to set a non-existent property, like Enabled for Label controls.

Try this

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
    ctl.Enabled = False            'Works for True or False
    ctl.Enabled = allowEditing     'Throws error
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a scope issue. If you want to globally use this Boolean between multiple forms, I suggest creating an Access table to hold global state variables. Just run queries on the table to get the values.

Comment: I thought so too, but I can hover over the variable in the debugger and see the correct value.